# Fragment Shader Draw Unexpected Border Line

Tags: libgdx, shader, fragment-shader

I have a shader program which will make a border line depends on alpha value arround each pixels. I hope to add a yellow border line along an image just like this:

[image]

However, it does not give me the expected answer. The thing that I cant understand the most is why there will always be a border line at one boundary side of image.

My fragment shader codes:

```
varying vec4 v_color; 
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

uniform vec2  u_imageSize;
uniform vec4  u_borderColor; 
uniform float u_borderSize;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    vec2 pixelToTextureCoords = 1. / u_imageSize;
    bool isInteriorPoint = true;
    bool isExteriorPoint = true;

    for (float dx = -u_borderSize; dx < u_borderSize; dx++)     
    {
        for (float dy = -u_borderSize; dy < u_borderSize; dy++){
            vec2 point = v_texCoords + vec2(dx,dy) * pixelToTextureCoords;
            float alpha = texture2D(u_texture, point).a;
            if ( alpha < 0.5 )
                isInteriorPoint = false;
            if ( alpha > 0.5 )
                isExteriorPoint = false;
        }
    }

    if (!isInteriorPoint && !isExteriorPoint && color.a < 0.5)
        gl_FragColor = u_borderColor;    
        else
        gl_FragColor = v_color * color;
}
```

My vertex shader codes:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform vec2 u_viewportInverse;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

My definition codes:

```
shaderProgram.setUniformf( "u_imageSize", new Vector2(getWidth(), getHeight()) );
                shaderProgram.setUniformf( "u_borderColor", Color.YELLOW );
                shaderProgram.setUniformf( "u_borderSize", 1 );
```

Outcome image(shape above is without shader and shape below is with shader):

[image]

Please provide me any kind of guides.

Comment: I didnt fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you upload a picture of the desired result?

Comment: @Nadir sorry for the incomplete information. I have added my desired image in the question. Please have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused, because the texture coordinates in the loop become *< 0.0* respectively *> 1.0*. So the texture is looked up "out of bounds". What happens in this case depends on the wrap parameters (see [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml).   Add a range check to the loop and skip the lookup when coordinates are not in range [0.0, 1.0], to solve the issue:

```c
for (float dx = -u_borderSize; dx < u_borderSize; dx++)     
{
    for (float dy = -u_borderSize; dy < u_borderSize; dy++){
        vec2 point = v_texCoords + vec2(dx,dy) * pixelToTextureCoords;

        // range check
        if (point.x < 0.0 || point.x > 1.0 || point.y < 0.0 || point.y > 1.0)
            continue;

        float alpha = texture2D(u_texture, point).a;
        if ( alpha < 0.5 )
            isInteriorPoint = false;
        if ( alpha > 0.5 )
            isExteriorPoint = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried with adding the range check but it makes no different in my case :(

Comment: Beside, I have added some extra information. Please kindly have a look on it.